# Email newsletter: changing color of email output doesn't works in Outlook

Tags: html, css, colors, outlook, newsletter

I have created a newsletter which displays the email address in the wrong color in Outlook. In the web version the email address is displayed in white without problems and in Outlook it is displayed in blue.

This is the part of the code:

```
<div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:320px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0;font-family: roboto, Arial, sans-serif;color:#ffffff;background-color:#393939;" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="inner" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px; font-size:0">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;font-family: roboto, Arial, sans-serif;color:#ffffff !important;width:100%;font-size:11px;text-align:left;text-decoration: none;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td color="color: #ffffff" style="padding:0; color: #ffffff !important">Ipsum Lorem:<br />
                                    <div style="color: #ffffff; font-family: roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">{$EMAIL}</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to change this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background` property is not supported in Word (only when there is a URL). The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML bodies. You can read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements and CSS properties in the following articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338200(v=office.12))

Comment: Thank you! I will change it.

Comment: That is not an argument.

Comment: Litmus is not Outlook.